# Script shell for calculate average time

Tags: shell, average

I have a directory with different type of logs, between them there is the logs whit the format *.log that contain:

> ```
> 12/05/2016 00:08:01 31463 trt_facture     START         
> 12/05/2016 00:08:15 31463 trt_facture                  
> 12/05/2016 00:08:30 31463 trt_facture                   
> 12/05/2016 00:08:30 31463 trt_facture                  
> 12/05/2016 00:08:30 31463 trt_facture     FIN
> ```

I want a shell script to calculate average time for these logs, for example : line 1 column 2, and line 2 column 2 and calculate average time, and store this information in another file and repeat same things for all files!!

Comment: so what would the expected result be? Is it always line 1 and the one below it, or the average of column 2?

Comment: result is a file with the average of column and repeat this action for another log files, something like this:                                                                             ```12/05/2016  5                                                                                                                    18/05/2016     6                                                                                               15/06/2016     3                                                                                                          ```

Comment: That just looks like your counting the lines that match `12/5/2016'.

Comment: no, i didn't calculate correctly it's just a example in fact it's like this: 30+1=31/2= 15.5 s

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$1==$1 { ++count } END { print $1,count }' file

12/05/2016 5
```

If you have multiple log file just put it in a `for` loop to output a file for each log

Comment: i need average time, for example: first line: 0*3600+8*60+1=481  last line: 0*3600+8*60+30= 510 510-481= 29 s and i save it in a file(ex: result.log) and so on... it's for that if for example this time was 30 minute that's mean there is a problem and in next step i want to write a script that verify result.log and in this case(duration plus 30 minute) send a mail for admin... i hope it is clear , my English isn't very well ;)

Comment: Sorry I am not following, maybe some else who can help better than me.... i will keep trying :)